# which directory to use for locating rails application files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, centos

I have developed a rails application in Ubuntu. Now i need to deploy in my VPS which has centos installed. It may be a silly question but i couldn't find a specific solution for it.

What confusing me is

```
1. Where do i place my rails application directory either in var/www/html or opt/ or any other location.
2. Whether i need to use my virtualhost for configuration of domain and sub domain.
```

Can anyone explain or provide any good reference links.

Answer (score 0):

create a new user with low privileges and deploy your application in a folder owned by that user. You may have trouble if you locate your rails application inside a users $HOME on centos due to SELinux. You can create a new folder such as `/my_applications/` in the root of your file system. to deploy your application. This will make it easy in future to migrate the application to another disk (if ever)

Other configurations depend on your choice of appserver / webserver.

After being on CentOS for close to 4 years, we made a switch to Ubuntu recently. I am glad we switched. Life gets easier with an OS preferred by the ruby/rails community.

Comment: Ok i created new user. Where to deploy my app whether in `/usr/`

Comment: Please read the answer above. You can deploy it anywhere other than a users home folder (and its sub folders - though there are ways to override this restriction). But I strongly recommend using a separate folder located in the root of the file system or on a separate disk if you have the luxury.

Comment: since i have very basic knowledge i cannot understand what `root of the file system means` whether `/var,/etc/ etc.,` with sub folder right?

Comment: Ok i have understood. But rails run in port number 3000. Whether i need to set server default port for 3000 or any other option to do it

Comment: Is this a development environment or production environment? Have you read the Rails getting started guide? It is very difficult to guide you if you have not done some basic homework yourself